# set font size of sankey chart in HIghcharter for R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have a cool sankey chart done in Hichcharts using R.
The ending node has a very small font size to my liking so i want to know how to make it bigger (and the container must be wider too).

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'sankey') %>%
  hc_add_series(
      data = list(
        list(from = 'FOOD', to = "M", weight = 10),
        list(from = 'CARS', to = "M",  weight = 50),
        list(from = 'READING', to = "M",  weight = 45),list(from = 'FOOD', to = "F", weight = 100),
        list(from = 'CARS', to = "F",  weight = 56),
        list(from = 'READING', to = "F",  weight = 25))
      )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the node width using series.nodeWidth property, but it works only for all nodes. If you want to set it only for a specific node, you would have to change the Highcharts core code.

The font size you can change in the dataLabels.nodeFormatter. Here is a pure JavaScript example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9tL2zogq

```
nodeWidth: 50,
    dataLabels: {
      nodeFormatter() {
        if (this.key === 'M' || this.key === 'F') {
          return '<span style="font-size: 22px;">' + this.key + '</span>'
        } else {
          return this.key
        }
      }
    },
```

Let me know if you have any problems with rewriting it to R, I will edit my answer then.
You can inject the JS function into R using JS() method.